# Deploying on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I installed the last version of visual studio to target windows phone 8.1 OS. After the installation I figured out that the 8.1 OS was not yet released and I couldn't deploy my application on my device. Can I target the windows phone 8.0 version when building the application?

Comment: You may think (if it's your phone) about installing Developer Preview to test your WP8.1 App.

Comment: Follow [the instructions here](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop/devpreview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Go to your project properties and there on your application tab, you can select the target OS.

[image]

Comment: The screen you have provided is only available for WP8.0 apps - if you had one created before or you start new app [like in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23802489/2681948). When starting the app, VS will ask you if you want to target WP8.0 or WP8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Select This Project Template & It will prompt you to select your targeting Windows Phone OS

[image: Select This Project Template & It will prompt you to select your targeting Windows Phone OS]

But Once you have targeted 8.1 you can't deploy on a 8.0 device or emulator.